# SQL Server partitioning when null

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

I have a sql server table like this:

```
Value   RowID   Diff
153     48      1
68      49      1
50      57      NULL
75      58      1
65      59      1
70      63      NULL
66      64      1
79      66      NULL
73      67      1
82      68      1
85      69      1
66      70      1
118     88      NULL
69      89      1
67      90      1
178     91      1
```

How can I make it like this (note the partition after each null in 3rd column):

```
Value   RowID   Diff
153     48      1
68      49      1
50      57      NULL
75      58      2
65      59      2
70      63      NULL
66      64      3
79      66      NULL
73      67      4
82      68      4
85      69      4
66      70      4
118     88      NULL
69      89      5
67      90      5
178     91      5
```

Comment: What's the query you used so far ?

Comment: SELECT C1.Value, C1.RowID, 
CASE WHEN C1.RowID-C2.RowID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END as Diff
 from CONSEC2 as C1 INNER JOIN CONSEC2 as C2 on C1.RowID2 = C2.RowID2+1   I basically want to find out the longest sequence of consecutive RowIDs. I thought if I had the 3rd column partitioned like that I could use Max(Count()) to determine the longest sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are partitioning over sequential values of `RowID`.  There is a trick to do this directly by grouping on `RowID - Row_Number()`:

```
select
  value,
  rowID,
  Diff,
  RowID - row_number() over (order by RowID) Diff2
from
  Table1
```

Notice how this gets you similar groupings, except with distinct Diff values (in Diff2):

```
| VALUE | ROWID |   DIFF | DIFF2 |
|-------|-------|--------|-------|
|   153 |    48 |      1 |    47 |
|    68 |    49 |      1 |    47 |
|    50 |    57 | (null) |    54 |
|    75 |    58 |      1 |    54 |
|    65 |    59 |      1 |    54 |
|    70 |    63 | (null) |    57 |
|    66 |    64 |      1 |    57 |
|    79 |    66 | (null) |    58 |
|    73 |    67 |      1 |    58 |
|    82 |    68 |      1 |    58 |
|    85 |    69 |      1 |    58 |
|    66 |    70 |      1 |    58 |
|   118 |    88 | (null) |    75 |
|    69 |    89 |      1 |    75 |
|    67 |    90 |      1 |    75 |
|   178 |    91 |      1 |    75 |
```

Then to get ordered values for `Diff`, you can use `Dense_Rank()` to produce a numbering over each separate partition - except when a value is `Null`:

```
select
  value,
  rowID,
  case when Diff = 1
  then dense_rank() over (order by Diff2)
  else Diff end as Diff
from (
  select
    value,
    rowID,
    Diff,
    RowID - row_number() over (order by RowID) Diff2
  from
    Table1
) T
```

The result is the expected result, except keyed off of `RowID` directly rather than off of the existing Diff column.

```
| VALUE | ROWID |   DIFF |
|-------|-------|--------|
|   153 |    48 |      1 |
|    68 |    49 |      1 |
|    50 |    57 | (null) |
|    75 |    58 |      2 |
|    65 |    59 |      2 |
|    70 |    63 | (null) |
|    66 |    64 |      3 |
|    79 |    66 | (null) |
|    73 |    67 |      4 |
|    82 |    68 |      4 |
|    85 |    69 |      4 |
|    66 |    70 |      4 |
|   118 |    88 | (null) |
|    69 |    89 |      5 |
|    67 |    90 |      5 |
|   178 |    91 |      5 |
```

Comment: `RowID - row_number() over (order by RowID) Diff2` This only works because there are gaps in RowID where there is a null, and is not based on where a null occurs. Not a criticism, but just want to point that out if that is not guaranteed.  I don't think it'd work if for example `49 |  1` was followed by `50 |   (null)` instead of 57